# Show intersection of non-parallel cylinders is bounded

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

First let me define what I mean by cylinder. Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $R > 0$ a real number. Then I call the set
$$
C_{R}(U) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^N\,:\,\|x - y\|_2 < R \;\text{for some y} \in U\}
$$
the cylinder with axis $U$ and radius $R$. Now let $U,V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be two one-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $R_1, R_2 > 0$. I want to show that the intersection $C_{R_1}(U) \cap C_{R_2}(V)$ is bounded if $U$ and $V$ are non-parallel subspaces. Intuitively this is clear: When the angle $\alpha$ between $U$ and $V$ is not equal to zero the cylinders intersect in a compact set. I have managed to show this by drawing a picture of the plane spanned by $U$ and $V$ and assuming that $R_1 \geq R_2$. Then the intersection can be seen to be contained in a ball of radius $\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})\cdot R_1$ centered at the origin.

My question: Can we show the boundedness of the intersection by means of linear algebra alone, i.e. without resorting to drawing a picture? My first idea was to consider the orthogonal decomposition of any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. For example decomposing $x$ with respect to $U$ we can write $x = u^{||} + u^{\perp}$, i.e. we get a parallel and a orthogonal part. With this we have $x \in C_{R_1}(U) \iff \|u^{\perp}\|_2 < R_1$. We can do the same with respect to the second subspace and obtain $x \in C_{R_2}(V) \iff \|v^{\perp}\|_2 < R_2$. Now it follows that $x = u^{||} + u^{\perp} = v^{||} + v^{\perp}$ is in the intersection of both cylinders iff $\|u^{\perp}\|_2 < R_1 \wedge \|v^{\perp}\|_2 < R_2$. However, the decompositions are of course with respect to different basis and also the angle between $U$ and $V$ doesn't appear anywhere so something is missing in this approach. Can it be salvaged? What is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $e$ and $f$ unit vectors in the directions of $U$ and $V$. They are linearly independent (otherwise the assertion is false). Choose $\lambda>0$ such that the projection of $\pm\lambda e$ onto $V^\perp$ satisfies
$$
\|P_{V^\perp}(\pm\lambda e)\|=R_1+R_2
$$
which is clearly possible by linearity. The lines play a symmetric role in the problem, so for the same $\lambda$ you have
$$
\|P_{U^\perp}(\pm\lambda f)\|=R_1+R_2
$$
If $x$ is in the intersection of the cylinders, there exist $y_1\in U$ and $y_2\in V$ such that
$$
\|x-y_1\|\le R_1,\quad \|x-y_2\|\le R_2\quad (*)
$$
Then, necessarily $\|y_1\|, \|y_2\|\le\lambda$. Proof: if $\|y_1\|>\lambda$ you have $dist (y_1,V)>R_1+R_2$ and no point $x$ can satisfy (*).

From (*) and the triangle inequality follows
$$
\|x\|-\|y_1\|\le R_1,\quad \|x\|-\|y_2\|\le R_2.
$$
Adding the above conditions,
$$
2\|x\|\le \|y_1\|+\|y_2\|+R_1+R_2\le 2\lambda+R_1+R_2,
$$
proving the assertion.